# Cannot move out of borrowed content in Rust

Tags: rust

```
pub struct Character {
    name: String,
    hp: i32,
    level: i32,
    xp: i32,
    xp_needed: i32,
    gold: i32
}

impl Character {
    pub fn new(name: String) -> Character {
        let mut rng = thread_rng();

        let hp: i32 = rng.gen_range(12, 75);
        let gold: i32 = rng.gen_range(10, 50);

        Character { name: name, hp: hp, level: 1, xp: 0, gold: gold, xp_needed: 100 }
    }

    pub fn get_name(&self) -> String {
        self.name
    }

    // ...
}
```

How exactly am I breaking the rules here?

> At a high-level, this is against-the-grain for Rust. You cannot transfer ownership of something borrowed because you don't own it.

Um don't I? I have other functions like:

```
pub fn get_hp(&self) -> i32 {
    self.hp
}
```

And that works just fine.

```
   |
23 |         self.name
   |         ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error: aborting due to previous error
```

What's going on? What is the appropriate approach to return the character name? Why does the `get_hp` method work but not `get_name`?

Comment: There are [*so many* other questions for the same error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+move+out+of+borrowed+content+is%3Aq). `i32` is `Copy`, `String` isn't. You **don't** own `self`, it's borrowed (`&self`).

Comment: @Shepmaster This doesn't answer my question or give me a solution.

Comment: TheWebs what @Shepmaster means is that you are supposed to show some effort in your question, and if there are other questions similar to yours, explain why their answers don't apply to your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between `get_hp` and `get_name` is that `get_hp` returns a `i32`. `i32` is a [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) type. `Copy` types can be copied by simply copying bits and are never moved out. On the other hand `String` is not `Copy`, it manages some memory which must either be transferred (moved out) or [`Clone`d](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html).

For getters like this, it is more idiomatic to return references instead of cloning. And for `String`s, it should specifically [be `&str`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-or-vec-vec/40006220).

```
pub fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
    &self.name
}
```