# Is there an operation for Rc or Arc which clones the underlying value and returns it to the caller?

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, reference-counting

I'm looking for something roughly like this `take`, but atomic:

```
impl<T: Clone> for Arc<T> {
    fn take(mut self) -> T {
        Arc::make_mut(&mut self);
        Arc::try_unwrap(self).unwrap()
    }
}
```

In other words, I want `Arc::make_mut` which returns the value itself, rather than a mutable reference.

Comment: What is the purpose of making the ref mutable if you are going to clone it anyway?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We can use [the `*` deref operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) to address the underlying value inside of an `Rc` or `Arc`, and then call `.clone()` to return a new owned clone of that value (assuming it's clonable).

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() { 
    let rc = Rc::new("Hello".to_string());
    let mut cloned = (*rc).clone();
    cloned.truncate(4);

    // verify that it's modified
    println!("{:?}", cloned); // "Hell"
    // verify that the original was not
    println!("{:?}", rc); // "Hello"
}
```

The `Rc`/`Arc` semantics will prevent any mutable references from being created while your reference exists, so this operation is thread-safe; the data can't be changed while you're cloning it. You also don't need a mutable reference to the original underlying value, because you're not modifying it.

In some cases, Rust lets you omit the `*` deref operator: it will implicitly dereference a non-mutable pointer type if you try to call a method that doesn't exist on the pointer, but does exist on the underlying value. However, we need to be explicit in this case because a `.clone()` method does already exists on `Rc`/`Arc`: it's used to create a new reference to the same value. We don't want to call that, so we need to explicitly dereference to access the inner type's `.clone()` instead.

We can also tell Rust which `.clone()` method we want by explicitly calling it through the appropriate type, and the compiler will implicitly apply as many dereferences as necessary.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() { 
    let rc3 = Rc::new(Rc::new(Rc::new("Hello".to_string())));
    let mut cloned = String::clone(&rc3);
    cloned.truncate(4);

    // verify that it's modified
    println!("{:?}", cloned); // "Hell"
    // verify that the original was not
    println!("{:?}", rc3); // "Hello"
}
```

Comment: In some cases, it may be clearer to use the fully-qualified syntax. It's annoying here due to the use of the array, but in general: `<[i32; 3]>::clone(&arc)`

Comment: @Shepmaster Good suggestion, thanks! I changed the types and added a quick example like that to the post. (Feel free to edit if you feel inclined.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer! I don't understand why it is not possible to deref an Arc pointer into a variable and then clone it? Borrow checker screams at me that I can't move out the value out of Arc, while (*Arc).clone() is technically the same?

Comment: @ArazAbishov if your type is not `Copy`, then what would the value of the `Arc` variable be if you moved the value out of it? See also [Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/155423); [Cannot move out of borrowed content in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40075031/155423); [Cannot move out of borrowed content when trying to transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28258548/155423); etc.

Comment: I see now @Shepmaster, thanks. For some reason (probably because of experience of working with other languages), I assumed that dereferencing would be equivalent of moving an object out. That's why (*arc).clone() was confusing to me.  Thanks again!

Comment: This clones the value anyway, even when not needed.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer may clone the data unnecessarily, even when there are no other strong references to it.

But you can do the following:

```rust
pub fn take<T: Clone>(v: Arc<T>) -> T {
    match Arc::try_unwrap(v) {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(v) => T::clone(&v),
    }
}
```

This will avoid cloning if there is only one strong reference, as does `make_mut()`.

Note that for `Rc` the code in the original post is enough as it doesn't need to be atomic.

Answer (score 3):

Since Rust 1.76.0 there is now [`Arc::unwrap_or_clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.unwrap_or_clone) and [`Rc::unwrap_or_clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.unwrap_or_clone), exactly for this use-case.